# Using NaCl to change the relative humidity in the humidity chamber

Tags: experimental-chemistry

The saturated NaCl will give around 75% RH in various temperature. Is there a way to use different concentration of NaCl in the water to generate different values of RH, i.e., 10% to 90% in the humidity chamber?

Comment: You can't go lower than 75%, but everything between 75% and 100% (pure water) is possible.

Comment: You need to use other salts. You can search for table of constant humidities of saturated solutions on internet and I remember I have posted some here in past too. // You can theoretically use NaCl for whole 75-100% range, but it would not be buffered nor the values are easily available.(can be non linear).

Comment: See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/112915/35806